# How to deploy wsdl using jboss

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jboss

I had created wsdl file using the axis codegen(JAVA2WSDL). The wsdl got generated on the local hard disk. I want to use it in order to call the methods exposed via it.
To do so, I think I have to deploy it in the server(am using JBoss). Can anyone tell me how I can do it ? Main aim is to access the methods exposed by the wsdl.

**Imp:**  I want to add that I had created the wsdl using axis codegen, and it doesen't have annotations like @webmethod or @webservice

Thanks

-Aj

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, you would create a Web project and export it in a EAR file. The EAR file would then contain a WAR file that would have all your generated class and WSDL.

What I do, is create a simple Web project in Eclipse, write my Services class and generate a web service using a tool like Axis. That way, Axis puts relevant servlets and filters on my web.xml and I export it to its relevant archive file (EAR/WAR) to publish to my application Server.

Comment: You mean, Web Service project (Ctrl+N/Web Service Wizard/Web Service , in eclipse) ? In that case, am getting some **'IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred.'**

Comment: @Ajj, I don't have this feature (with Eclipse Indigo). I create a simple Dynamic Web Project, write my classes, generate web service and done. :)

Comment: Oh ok. I am following the steps(Dynamic web project). Where to add the class files? In 'build' folder ?

Comment: It will have to be in build folder since the classes in build folder gets exported. I would suggest not transferring codes but to generate your WSDL from the web project directly.

Comment: Well I had written it and run the jboss. I dint find anything in jboss/..../deploy folder

Comment: I have done the way you have asked to. Generated the wsdl too. But how to know what its url is?

Comment: That depends on which directory structure is your WSDL generated in your project (if it's outside `WEB-INF` folder (or not)).

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2956/discussion-between-ajj-and-the-elite-gentleman)

Comment: It got created outside WEB-INF, in wsdl folder.

Comment: Then possible url is `http://localhost:8080/<appName>/wsdl/<wsdlName>.wsdl` (once deployed in JBoss, of course. :)).

Comment: Need your help gentleman: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239171/error-failed-while-installing-axis2-web-services-core-1-1-while-setting-axis2