# Error 'Failed while installing Axis2 Web Services Core 1.1' , while setting Axis2 Web Services Facet

Tags: eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I am trying to implement web services using axis2, in Eclipse. (I had downloaded axis2-1.5 runtime and created environment variable for it.)  I had created a dynamic web project and set the axis2 runtime successfully in Axis2 preferences.

After creating the project, I tried setting the project facet, but end up getting the following error: **Failed while installing Axis2 Web Services Core 1.1**

Stack shows only:**NullPointerException**(which is not helping me much in understanding the problem). Wat could be the problem? Without this, it's difficult to test web services using axis2.

**(P.S: While creating the dynamic project, I didnt get any option to set the project facet, thus, I had to try setting the project facet, after creating the project. I was following the tutorial given at --> [Web Services using axis2 tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html))**

Thanks

Comment: Are you running [Eclipse IDE For Java EE Developers](http://eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php)?

Comment: Yes. Eclipse IDE-3.7 Indigo for JAVA EE Developers

Comment: Strange, because I have the "Axis 2 Web Services" in Eclipse Indigo (in my web project properties).

Comment: Even I have Web Services Wizard. Problem is no that.

Comment: I'm with the same error here. It seems a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327800). Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to set up using Eclipse 3.6 and the error dint show up.