# unable to add the following facets axis2 web services core

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-axis

For one of my project, I required to create Web service using Apache Axis2.
I started reading about the framework and followed the guideline given [here](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html).
However, I am getting an error "**Failed While Installing Axis 2 Web Services Core 1.1**".

Also when I tried to explicitly create the web service on the same project, I am getting error "**unable to add the following facets axis2 web services core**". I have referred this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239171/error-failed-while-installing-axis2-web-services-core-1-1-while-setting-axis) too, but since I am already using **Eclipse 3.6 (Helios)**, the answer does not work for me.

Thank you for the help...

Comment: You could try downloading the axis2 files and generate the code via command line instead?

Comment: I tried by taking sample "QuickStart" and creating web service using Ant Build, the web service (i.e. WSDL file) was created, however, we could not be able to communicate through that service and getting Error: 404.